# Is there any Maven cmd that can only build test without the whole project?

Tags: java, maven, junit4

I have a big server project, and some related UnitTest file using maven.

When I added the new UnitTest for some java file, I only want to build the current UnitTest and run it, I don't want to build the whole server project from the beginner.

But when I using the:

> mvn test -Dtest=NewUnitTest

I still need to wait for a long time to build the whole server project.

Is there a way to only build the new added UnitTest file?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not simply compile&run the test in your IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following one:

```
mvn compiler:testCompile surefire:test -Dtest=NewUnitTest
```

- *[compiler:testCompile](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/testCompile-mojo.html)* - will compile your tests (if you need it)
- *[surefire:test](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html)* - will execute your tests

Comment: Thanks for replying me. :) When I try to run this cmd as you mentioned:
> mvn surefire:test -Dtest=NewUnitTest
I got this error: 
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.
16:test (default-cli) on project server: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfN
oTests=false to ignore this error.) -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 0):

how are you doing this?

If you run a clean and then compile it will delete everything and then compile.

If you simply run [mvn test-compile](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/testCompile-mojo.html) then it should just compile anything that is outdated including any test code

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have multi-module build. Just run (from the root):

`mvn clean test -Dtest=NewUnitTest -pl :<the artifactId of the project you want to test>`

Obviously, if the project you are trying to test depends on other artifacts in your reactor, you may need to build these too if they can't be fetched from a centralized repository. Just add the "also-make" flag (`-am`):

`mvn clean test -Dtest=NewUnitTest -pl :<the artifactId of the project you want to test> -am`